# Laravel API: Throw not found error if user not exist in database Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a login/register API and when the user tries to login with the wrong email/password and with credentials that don't exist in the database, they produce the same response which is this:

[image]

What I want to do is separate the responses; When the user tries to login with the wrong email/password, `'Invalid Credentials'` will be the response and when the user tries to login with credentials that don't exist in the database, the response should be `'User Does Not Exist!'`

This is my code in the login controller:

```
 $loginData = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'email|required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        if (!auth()->attempt($loginData)) {
            return response(['message' => 'Invalid Credentials']);
        }
```

Comment: Because `auth()` method is disabled for API. You should  use Sanctum , Passport or any other  authentication method

Comment: It is just a step away from message "You typed password <password_1>. Are you sure your password is not <password_2>?" You don't need separate response. "Incorrect/invalid credentials." is just fine message. If you are not convinced with this comment of mine, between lines in your code above you can write `if (!User::where(['email' => $request->input('email')])->exists()) { return response(['message' => 'Resource not found'], 404); }`. Again you don't want to give more info about your system than needed and invalid credentials is just fine according to modern security standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any columns as an action for the authentication process. According to the documentation,

> The attempt method will return true if authentication was successful.
> Otherwise, false will be returned.

And you can apply conditions as many you want inside the attempt method by passing array of columns like.

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])) {
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
```

So here we reached at a conclusion that, we can use this method to determine that if specific user exists in database by matching different columns.

Therefor, we can use the same **attempt** method for different purposes. like for checking if **only email** exists in database like,

```
if (! Auth::attempt(['email' => $email])) {
    // user doesn't exists in database 
}
```

and so on. Further, if this scenario doesn't work, you may use eloquent or DB Builder just for special purpose besides from email/password authentication action.

Thanks mate,